# MS-Access, Continuous form of multiple clients - Form.Text field containing Last Communication for Each Client / Customer in List

Tags: forms, date, ms-access-2016, aggregates

I am a First time user of StackOverFlow here! 
I have been trying to figure this out for two days and have come up short.

We have a form that displays every single Client / Customer that we have at the firm, in a continuous form view.

We want to be able to display on this form the date, for each client, when we last communicated, or called, the client. (We want to be sure that we prevent a situation where we have not called a client for more than 1.5 months).

I have a query on a table tracking our correspondence, and other activities, regarding our clients that, in SQL, looks like:

```
' Query ContactCommunications  
SELECT Context, ID, NoteDate, ContactID
FROM Comments
WHERE (((Context)="Communication with Client" Or (Context)="Phone Call with Client"));
```

> (ContactID is a secondary key for Contacts table - we are tracking not
>   only clients but also opposing parties and such)

This is intended to show all the dates we called or communicated with our clients.

I have a second query that then gets the Last Date from this table, grouped by ContactID, which looks like:

```
' Query qryLastCommunicationAgg  
SELECT ContactID, Last(CommentDate) AS LastOfCommentDate
FROM Comments INNER JOIN qryContactCommunications 
     ON Comments.ID = qryContactCommunications.ID
GROUP BY Comments.ContactID;
```

My question is how do I get the query result (When we last called each client) into a text field in our Continuous form list? At the moment there will be some null values as well.

I have tried the expression:

```
=DLookUp("CommentDate","qryLastCommunicationAgg",[ID]=[ContactID])
```

But it does not work, giving me #Name?

Not sure what I did wrong. :-(
I appreciate greatly any assistance or suggestions! 
-Glenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use Max:

```
SELECT ContactID, Max(CommentDate) AS LastOfCommentDate
```

Then try with:

```
=DLookUp("LastCommentDate","qryLastCommunicationAgg","[ID]=" & [ContactID] & "")
```

("Below is the fixed version of the DLookup script - Glenn")

```
=DLookUp("LastOfCommentDate","qryLastCommunicationAgg","[ContactID]=" & [ID] & "")
```

Comment: <pre><code>=DLookUp("LastofCommentDate","qryLastCommunicationAgg","[ID]=" & [ContactID] & "")
Did not work unfortunately.
Do I need to refer to the form itself in that expression? This is so that the data from the query is inserted into a form text box field. The form's name is ClientList

Comment: I got it! Thank you much @Gustav!
I had to reverse the criteria around to this: =DLookUp("LastOfCommentDate","qryLastCommunicationAgg","[ContactID]=" & [ID] & "")
Works great now! You can't imagine the headache this gave me. Felt like I was banging my head against a wall for a while.